# Is it impossible to add in layout to new empty xml file through android studio's design window's layout palette?

Tags: android-studio

As you all know android studio offers an easy way to generate layout xml files through drag and dropping design palette's items. But if you try to do this on an empty xml file, the drag and drop won't work. It seem that this function is only operational on automatically generated layout file, or at least layout tag written by hand coding at its simplest level. Is it simply just impossible to apply this function on an empty file or am I missing something?
By the way, the android studio version is 2.1.1